# disabling transactional fixtures in Rspec has no effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures, rspec2

Due to a legacy database I'm using, I'm stuck with MySQL using MyISAM, which means my tables don't support transactions. This is causing the tests to fail, since table data generated (I'm using factory_girl for fixtures) by the tests are not reverted for each scenario.

I discovered that Rspec exposes the `config.use_transactional_fixtures` config setting in spec_helper.rb.

which is set to true by default. When I set it to false, I don't see any effect on my tests; they still fail due to duplicate records.

Isn't that setting supposed to automatically unroll any changes made to the DB? Or am I supposed to do that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - if your database doesn't support transactions you must issue several SQL commands to wipe out data before each statement:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename;
```

One for each of your tables.

In your helper.rb try this:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    tables = %{users posts tags}
    tables.each do |t|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE #{t}')
    end
  end
  ... 
end
```

Comment: Cool, thanks; I was under the impression that Rails somehow automates this.